# Which method of word substitution or replacing is more quick?

Tags: java, string, performance, substitution, replaceall

I have a program, which substitutes a word with another word.

I was wondering which one will be more quick out of two options.(I am retrieving the values from a HashMap| Original word is the key| Word to be substituted is the value)

1. Take all the keys of map one by one and then call "replaceAll" method for each of them on the String.
2. Splitting the String by "split" method and then substituting each one of the word of the array with the map.

(String can become 8 mb or more in cases)

Comment: First would build the string over and over again, second would copy the string twice (to the array and back) so I suspect it would be generally faster, depending on how many substitutions you needed to do. You could also look to build a regex with all the words in it and use [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) to swap in a single pass - whether that’s faster than the split would need testing - it would definitely be more robust.

Comment: Or you can use `matcher.replaceAll(m -> map.get(m.group()))`

Comment: Usual performance recommendation: first, write the most straightforward code (probably option 1), then test with typical parameters whether performance is okay (you need to know what "okay" means for your application). Only optimize if you find out there's a problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.